Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}=-\frac{H_{n+m}-H_{m}}{m!}$
I have no idea how to prove it. Could someone teach me?
info: $-H_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$
The book suggests using the following formula to solve the problem:
$\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)} = -H_{n+1}+1$

Try $\frac{1}{k}=\int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1}\ dx$. This computation occurs in the so called coupon collector's problem  when computing the expectation of the time to collect all coupons, from the probability mass function.

You may induct on $m$, for example, using the relation $\frac{m!}{k(k+1)\ldots (k+m)}=\frac{(m-1)!}{k(k+1)\ldots (k+m-1)}-\frac{(m-1)!}{(k+1)\ldots (k+m)}$, the sum reduces to the alternating sum of binomials $\sum (-1)^k{n+m\choose k+m}$ which is well known and easy

Here's one approach, using the beta integral $\int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^b \, dx = a!\,b!/(a+b+1)!$.
First note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom nk (1-x)^{k-1} &=\frac{[1-(1-x)]^n -1}{1-x}=\frac{x^n-1}{1-x}\notag\\
  &= -(1+x+\dotsb + x^{n-1}).\tag{$*$}\label{484971_star}
\end{align*}
Then the sum in question is
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom nk \frac{(k-1)!}{(k+m)!}
  &=\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom nk \int_0^1 (1-x)^{k-1}x^m\, dx\\
  &=-\frac{1}{m!} \int_0^1 (x^m+x^{m+1}+\dotsb + x^{m+n-1})\, dx \quad\text{by \eqref{484971_star}}\\
  &=-\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{1}{m+2}+\dotsb +\frac{1}{m+n}\right).
\end{align}

The book suggests using the following formula to solve the problem:
$\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)} = -H_{n+1}+1$. How to solve the problem with this?

Ira beat me to it while I was typing this answer, but I will post it anyway because of the different emphasis on iterated integrals, following my previous comment above.
Let
$$
\Theta_{m,n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}
\frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}\ .
$$
We then have
$$
\Theta_{m,n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}
(-1)^{k}
\int_{0}^{1}dx_0
\int_{0}^{x_0}dx_1
\int_{0}^{x_1}dx_2\cdots
\int_{0}^{x_{m-2}}dx_{m-1}
\int_{0}^{x_{m-1}}dx_m\ x_m^{k-1}
$$
$$
=\int_{1>x_0>\cdots>x_m>0}dx_0\cdots dx_m
\frac{1}{x_m}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}
(-x_m)^{k}
$$
$$
=\int_{1>x_0>\cdots>x_m>0}dx_0\cdots dx_m
\frac{1}{x_m}[(1-x_m)^n-1]
$$
$$
=-\int_{1>x_0>\cdots>x_m>0}dx_0\cdots dx_m
[(1-x_m)^{n-1}+(1-x_m)^{n-2}+\cdots+(1-x_m)+1]\ .
$$
For fixed $x_m$, the integration over the other $m$ variables gives a factor $\frac{(1-x_m)^m}{m!}$, as explained in
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753212/is-there-any-geometric-intuition-for-the-factorials-in-taylor-expansions/3753600#3753600
which is also my preferred derivation of the Taylor formula with integral remainder.
Hence we arrive at
$$
\Theta_{m,n}=-\int_{0}^{1}dx_m\ \frac{(1-x_m)^m}{m!}[(1-x_m)^{n-1}+(1-x_m)^{n-2}+\cdots+(1-x_m)+1]
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{m!}\int_0^1 du\ [u^{m+n+1}+u^{m+n-2}+\cdots+u^m]
$$
after the change of variable $u=1-x_m$.
Finally,
$$
\Theta_{m,n}=-\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{1}{m+n}+\frac{1}{m+n-1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{m+1}\right)=-\frac{1}{m!}(H_{m+n}-H_{m})
$$
is the wanted formula in terms of harmonic numbers.
In the famous coupon collector's problem in probability, the expectation $E[T]$ of the number of boxes one must open in order to get all the $n$ coupon types is $n H_n$, which follows easily from writing the random variable $T$ as a sum of geometric random variables. However, the probability mass function is
$$
\mathbb{P}(T=\ell)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}
\binom{n}{j} \frac{j}{n}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)^{\ell-1}\ ,
$$
which can be obtained by the inclusion-exclusion principle.
Trying to compute the expectation via $E[T]=\sum_{\ell}\ell\ \mathbb{P}(T=\ell)$, leads to the kind of identity like the one in the post.

The book suggests using the following formula to solve the problem:
$\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)} = -H_{n+1}+1$. How to solve the problem with this?

It seems the book asks for a solution along the line of the comment by Fedor Petrov. But why care about the book anyway?
